# react-navigation squash navigation stack but preserve rendering?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm running in to an issue with `react-navigation` and a basic `StackNavigator` where I'd like to navigate back to `HomeScreen` while preserving the initial render of that component and not "reset" it. It would be compared to multiple `goBack()` calls until `HomeScreen` is hit, but in one navigation.

App structure:

```
- StackNavigator
  - HomeScreen
  - ChannelScreen
  - VideoScreen
```

There is, however cyclical navigation on `ChannelScreen`, where you can click another related section and get to another `ChannelScreen`.

Quickly, the `StackNavigator` becomes: `HomeScreen` => `ChannelScreen`=> `ChannelScreen`=> `ChannelScreen` => `etc...`

We wanted an easy way to get back to `HomeScreen`, from any `ChannelScreen` so I employed a basic `reset` action:

```
export const resetStackNavigate = (navigation, routeName, params = {}) => {
  const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    params,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName })
    ]
  })
  navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
}
```

which works amazingly well with the exception that the reset causes the stack to "reset" so the initial `HomeScreen` is unmounted and remounted, and all the components/images/etc have to be reloaded.

I've also tried to pass the `HomeScreen`'s `state.key` (looks like: `Init-id-1513113862825-1`) down to the `ChannelScreen` and utilize:

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(this.props.navigation.state.params.homeScreenKey);
```

and

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back({ key: this.props.navigation.state.params.homeScreenKey }));
```

Both which did nothing.

Is there a way to get back to `HomeScreen` but preserve the initial screen?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by caching the first `ChannelScreen`'s `this.props.navigation.state.key` on navigation to the sub `ChannelsScreens`:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    _navigateToHome = () => {
        const { backKey } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        this.props.navigation.goBack(backKey);
    }

    _navigateToChannel = () => {
        let { backKey } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        if(!backKey) {
            backKey = this.props.navigation.state.key
        }
        navigate('Channel', { backKey });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {/* the link to another Channel */}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._navigateToChannel}>
                    {/* ... */}
                </TouchableOpacity>

                {/* Return to HomeScreen */}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._navigateToHome}>
                    {/* ... */}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

If you are on the first `ChannelScreen`, `backKey` will be *null* and therefore just `.goBack()` is called. On each subsequent `ChannelScreen` the first `ChannelScreen`'s `key` is passed along allowing `.goBack(key)` to navigate us back to the `HomeScreen`.